# Long text Won't Update

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, sql-update

I am trying to update my long text mysql field. It has been working previously with no issues what-so-ever, but all of sudden now it won't update. Here is the code

```
$productTitle = $_POST['product_title'];
$productDesc = $_POST['product_desc'];

$updateProductDesc = "UPDATE product_desc SET product_desc='$productDesc' 
WHERE product_sku='$productSku' ";
mysql_query($updateProductDesc, $db_custom);
```

I know I should be using mysqli but other than that all the syntax is correct. Or am I completely missing something.

Comment: Is the table name `product_desc` correct ?

Comment: Won't update means? use `mysql_error()` to debug the error. I think may be single quotes creating problem. Use `mysql_escape_string` to escape them.

Comment: I hope that this bug report can be useful http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12157

Comment: it was because there was apostrophe in the text being inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many reasons your code will not work:

**Step 1**

Change

```
$productDesc = $_POST['product_desc'];
```

Into

```
$productDesc = addslashes($_POST['product_desc']);
```

**Step 2**

Before update, add `mysql_real_escape_string($productDesc);`

Check your database and put `product_desc` type on TEXT

**Step 3**

Verify if `product_sku='$productSku'` is viable.

**Extra step**

mysql_query() is depreciated. Go for mysqli

Comment: This worked great! Thanks it was because of the apostrophe(s) and other special characters

Answer (score 0):

If all has been well before, odds are that your description field has some offending character. Yogesh Suthar is right that you should check the error. Try escaping the value with mysql_escape_string()